# practical uses of Aware interface in spring

Tags: spring

If I implement `ApplicationContextAware` interface to my bean then I will get an instance of `ApplicationContext` in my bean, but what is the **practical** use of it? why do we need `*Aware` interfaces, why should I bind my code with spring?

Comment: The javaodc explains it: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html. Remember that this interface is very old. Most of the cases where it was useful in the past are now doable with better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

According to spring [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-aware):

> Thus beans can manipulate programmatically the ApplicationContext that
>   created them, through the ApplicationContext interface, or by casting
>   the reference to a known subclass of this interface, such as
>   ConfigurableApplicationContext, which exposes additional
>   functionality. **One use would be the programmatic retrieval of other
>   beans**. Sometimes this capability is useful; however, in general you
>   should avoid it, because it couples the code to Spring and does not
>   follow the Inversion of Control style, where collaborators are
>   provided to beans as properties. **Other methods of the
>   ApplicationContext provide access to file resources, publishing
>   application events, and accessing a MessageSource.**

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have reference to application context if you want to publish Application event from your component, or have reference to `MessageSource` provided by [`MessageSourceAware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSourceAware.html) if you want to retrieve some message.

But as JB Nizet mentions in his comment, there are usually better alternatives. For instance you can usually Autowire `MessageSource` or `ApplicationEventPublisher` and other components provided by the `*Aware` interfaces, so there is usually no need for implementing these interfaces anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we have requirements that while creating the [Bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html) we need to access the 
[ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) , 
[ApplicationContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) and [Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html).

To accomplish the above requirements we are provided with many [Aware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware.html) interfaces from Spring.